# Secure websockets with Happstack

Tags: haskell, ssl, websocket, happstack

Is there a way to use secure websockets (`wss://`) in Haskell server-side (preferably with Happstack)?

I tried to search Cabal for websocket server implementations, I get `websockets` and its multiple wrappers for different frameworks. Search inside `websockets` package does not show anything related to TLS.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like most people nowadays use `nginx` as a reverse proxy capable of TLS (de)serialization, so the haskell backend only handles unencrypted data with `ws://` hanlders.